# .NetCore 5, EF 5: Startwith throws Exception with SqlNullabilityProcessor

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-5

1. I´m using "MySql.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.5"and "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.8".
2. following is a Model-Class "Customer"

```cs
    public class Customer
    {
    [Key]
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    }
```

3. following is a Context-Class:

```cs
    public class DataContext:DbContext
    {
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
    
    optionsBuilder.UseMySQL(connectionString: @"server=localhost;database=Test;uid=xyz;password=abcd;SSL mode=none");
    }
    
    public DataContext()
    {
    
    }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    }
```

3. I want to execute this code:

```cs
    DataContext ctx = new DataContext();
    
    string test = "test";
    
    List<Customer> customers=ctx.Customers.Where(m => m.Lastname.StartsWith(test)).ToList();
```

On executing the last line I get the exception:

> Unhandled expression
> '[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SqlParameterExpression]
> COLLATE utf8mb4_bin' of type
> 'MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Expressions.Internal.MySQLCollateExpression'
> encountered in 'SqlNullabilityProcessor'.

with the stacktrace:

> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.VisitCustomSqlExpression(SqlExpression
> sqlExpression, Boolean allowOptimizedExpansion, Boolean& nullable) at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.Visit(SqlExpression
> sqlExpression, Boolean allowOptimizedExpansion, Boolean
> preserveNonNullableColumns, Boolean& nullable) at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.Visit(SqlExpression
> sqlExpression, Boolean allowOptimizedExpansion, Boolean& nullable) at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.Visit(SqlExpression
> sqlExpression, Boolean& nullable) at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.VisitSqlFunction(SqlFunctionExpression
> sqlFunctionExpression, Boolean allowOptimizedExpansion, Boolean&
> nullable) at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.Visit(SqlExpression
> sqlExpression, Boolean allowOptimizedExpansion, Boolean
> preserveNonNullableColumns, Boolean& nullable) at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.Visit(SqlExpression
> sqlExpression, Boolean allowOptimizedExpansion, Boolean& nullable) at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.Visit(SqlExpression
> sqlExpression, Boolean& nullable) at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.VisitSqlFunction(SqlFunctionExpression
> sqlFunctionExpression, Boolean allowOptimizedExpansion, Boolean&
> nullable) at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.Visit(SqlExpression
> sqlExpression, Boolean allowOptimizedExpansion, Boolean
> preserveNonNullableColumns, Boolean& nullable) at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.VisitSqlBinary(SqlBinaryExpression
> sqlBinaryExpression, Boolean allowOptimizedExpansion, Boolean&
> nullable) at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.Visit(SqlExpression
> sqlExpression, Boolean allowOptimizedExpansion, Boolean
> preserveNonNullableColumns, Boolean& nullable) at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.VisitSqlBinary(SqlBinaryExpression
> sqlBinaryExpression, Boolean allowOptimizedExpansion, Boolean&
> nullable) at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.Visit(SqlExpression
> sqlExpression, Boolean allowOptimizedExpansion, Boolean
> preserveNonNullableColumns, Boolean& nullable) at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.VisitSqlBinary(SqlBinaryExpression
> sqlBinaryExpression, Boolean allowOptimizedExpansion, Boolean&
> nullable) at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.Visit(SqlExpression
> sqlExpression, Boolean allowOptimizedExpansion, Boolean
> preserveNonNullableColumns, Boolean& nullable) at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.VisitSqlBinary(SqlBinaryExpression
> sqlBinaryExpression, Boolean allowOptimizedExpansion, Boolean&
> nullable) at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.Visit(SqlExpression
> sqlExpression, Boolean allowOptimizedExpansion, Boolean
> preserveNonNullableColumns, Boolean& nullable) at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.VisitSqlBinary(SqlBinaryExpression
> sqlBinaryExpression, Boolean allowOptimizedExpansion, Boolean&
> nullable) at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.Visit(SqlExpression
> sqlExpression, Boolean allowOptimizedExpansion, Boolean
> preserveNonNullableColumns, Boolean& nullable) at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.Visit(SqlExpression
> sqlExpression, Boolean allowOptimizedExpansion, Boolean& nullable) at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.Visit(SelectExpression
> selectExpression) at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlNullabilityProcessor.Process(SelectExpression
> selectExpression, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues, Boolean& canCache) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalParameterBasedSqlProcessor.ProcessSqlNullability(SelectExpression selectExpression, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parametersValues, Boolean&
> canCache) at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalParameterBasedSqlProcessor.Optimize(SelectExpression
> selectExpression, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parametersValues, Boolean& canCache) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalCommandCache.GetRelationalCommand(IReadOnlyDictionary`2
> parameters) at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result) at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
> at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at
> EF5CoreTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> D:\Temp\obi\EF5CoreTest\EF5CoreTest\Program.cs:line 14

This works with .NetCore 5.0 and MySql.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.14.

can anyone help?

best regards

Comment: Enable logging in OnConfiguring (`optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information);` in EF Core 5) and check the generated SQL SELECT Statement. Are there records with Lastname = NULL in your table?

Comment: there is no additional output with LogLevel.Information. So i think the exception is thrown before executing a SQL-Statement.
the table is empty

Comment: Try your query with a hardcoded string (`.Where(m => m.Lastname.StartsWith("A")`). If this works the MySQL driver for EF Core has a problem with referenced variables.

Comment: replacing with hardcoded string has the same result

Comment: With LogLevel.Debug there is following output for the Generated Query Execution Expression:

              SELECT c.Key, c.Lastname
              FROM Customers AS c
              WHERE (c.Lastname != NULL) && (('test' != NULL) && ((c.Lastname LIKE CONCAT('test', '%')) && (LEFT(c.Lastname, CHAR_LENGTH([SqlExpressions.SqlConstantExpression] COLLATE utf8mb4_bin)) == [SqlExpressions.SqlConstantExpression] COLLATE utf8mb4_bin))))

Comment: A bug report (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=103436) addresses problems with empty tables: *The problem seems to occur when trying to compare dates when there is a possibility of there being no date to compare to (ie. table being empty, other criteria not resulting in a match etc.)*  I think this is the same problem. I tried EF and MySQL 15 years ago, it was a pain. And I see nothing has changed.

Comment: yes - i saw this also. the solution proposal on this bug doesn´t work.
The exception occurs even if the table is not empty.
I think this exception is thrown before the SQL is executed...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error when updating my project to use EF6.

It has been identified as a bug in MySql: [.NetCore 5, EF 5: Startwith throws Exception with SqlNullabilityProcessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68698868/netcore-5-ef-5-startwith-throws-exception-with-sqlnullabilityprocessor)

In the issue reported above, the problem was trying to compare a DateTime in a Linq expression.

My problem was more fundamental but has the same root cause. Below are the original line of text with the problem, and the replacement line that works.

Not working:

```
if (!_dbContext.Users.Any(x => x.Email.Equals(email, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
```

and working:

```
if (!_dbContext.Users.Any(x => x.Email == email))
```

It seems like Linq isn't allowing anything but simple types to be compared.